# How to allow both http1 and http2 requests in hyper?

Tags: rust, http2, hyper

I'm building a proxy service in rust with hyper and I want to support both HTTP1 and HTTP2 requests.  If I send a request where `request.version() == "HTTP/2.0".to_owned()` I get the warning

```
WARN  hyper::client::client  "Connection is HTTP/1, but request requires HTTP/2"
```

followed by the error

```
request has unsupported HTTP version
```

If I build my `hyper::Client` with `client_builder.http2_only(true)` I can send http2 requests, but that method clearly states that I [won't be able to send http1 requests](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.16/hyper/client/struct.Builder.html#method.http2_only), which I still want to support.  The documentation and the code in `hyper::client::Builder` seems to imply that it supports HTTP1 and HTTP2 by default (if the http2 feature is enabled) by it's `client_config.ver` field is either [`Ver::Auto` or `Ver::Http2`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.16/src/hyper/client/client.rs.html#1091-1094).

I dug deeper into the code that gave the above warning and I see that it's checking if the [pooled connection is HTTP1](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.16/src/hyper/client/client.rs.html#241) and erroring if the request is also HTTP2.  I'm seeing no way to make that connection HTTP2 short of forcing everything to be HTTP2 with `only_http2`.

Is it really impossible for a `hyper::client::Client` to support sending http2 and http1 requests?  Must I maintain two separate clients and branch on the requests version?